# Generating numbers for a Normal Distribution Histogram?

Tags: c

I'm working on generating numbers, distributed Normally, for a histogram. Here's my two functions. first for generating, second for transforming them to normal distribution. For some reason, it's just returning min negative numbers when I do the test printf's. Anybody know anything about this? Thanks!

```
double s, u[1000], v[1000], z;
int transformed[1000];

void generateec(){
srand( time(NULL) );
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
 {
 u[i] = rand() % 7-3;
 v[i] = rand() % 7-3;
 }

}

void transform(){
generateec();




for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    s = (u[i]*u[i])+(v[i]*v[i]);
    transformed[i] = u[i]*(sqrt( (-2.0 * log(s) ) / s)); 

}

printf("%d %d %d \n", transformed[0], transformed[500], transformed[600]);

 }
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: is this supposed to be C or C++? These are different languages. (I would guess C from what I see, but then remove the C++ tag) And please indent your code properly, this hurts the eye.

Comment: without the declaration of your variables this is much of guess work for us to do.

Comment: Running now, I either get zero, or -2147483648 as my values for the three test prints.

Comment: Note that `rand` gives you integer numbers, so there's a nonzero probability for `u[i] == 0` or both `v[i]` and `u[i]` to be zero, this does weird things to your formulas

Comment: I may be mistaken, but it looks to me you are sending negative numbers into `sqrt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it appears that you're trying to implement the Box-Muller's transform. But there're a couple of problems with your code.

Firstly, you need a continuous uniform distribution, not a discrete one, so

```
u[i] = (double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX);
v[i] = (double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX);
```

Then, the transformation part is hugely off, see [Box Muller Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_Muller_transform) , it must be along the lines of

```
transformed[i] = sqrt(-2.0 * log(u[i])) * cos(2 * pi * v[i]) ;
```

where `pi = atan(1)*4`.

Note that there're `2 * 1000` numbers with a normal distribution generated, so you can define `transformed` as `double transformed[2000];` and do this

```
transformed[2*i] = sqrt(-2.0 * log(u[i])) * cos(2 * pi * v[i]); 
transformed[2*i+1] = sqrt(-2.0 * log(u[i])) * sin(2 * pi * v[i]);
```

Note that there's a nonzero probability to still get `u[i] * v[i] == 0`. I leave this up to you to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

In:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    u[i] = rand() % 1;
    v[i] = rand() % 1;
 }
```

the expression:

```
rand() % 1
```

always yields `0`.

**EDIT**:

as the program was edited in the meantime, now the problem is the argument of `sqrt` function in your program can be a negative value. If `sqrt` argument is negative a domain error occurs and `sqrt` will return an implementation-defined value.

Comment: True, thanks. I've changed that now, but the numbers I'm getting are still huge.

Comment: You have changed the expression by what?

Comment: The question originally asked me to generate numbers between -3 and 3, so i've just changed it to this: u[i] = rand() % 7-3;
      v[i] = rand() % 7-3;

Comment: @Rupert the argument to `sqrt` in your program can be negative.